# How can I stop Eclipse from helping me and overriding what the 'End' key does?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, preferences

Eclipse is being helpful again, and I want it to stop. The situation is this:

1. It auto-completes a function name, to `foo()`, and because takes an argument, the cursor is now between the `()`.
2. I fill in the argument, and because the line still needs a semicolon at the end of line, I press the <kbd>End</kbd> key.
3. The cursor jumps to the end of the line (after the closing paren), and I press the <kbd>;</kbd> key.
4. Eclipse is being dumb, jumps back into the parens, selects my argument, and replaces it with the semicolon.

Result: `foo(;)`

Why is it doing this, and how do I stop it? It's bad enough that Eclipse is doing something ridiculous here, but I can't even explain what it is that it is trying to achieve!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Return</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>End</kbd>. Eclipse will then jump to the end of the line for you to insert your semicolon.

Comment: Lovely. That works, but it requires building new muscle memory that will be useful only in Eclipse, and a trap in any other Editor. Thanks for the tip - I still don't understand why it can't just work the way I expect it to :-)

Comment: Hit Escape before End, then, to snap it out of its helpful auto-complete mode.

Comment: There is an auto-semicolon preference option in Eclipse. It allows you to simply type ';' and it will (most of the time) position itself correctly.

Comment: Uriah: you're quite right. It's under Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing. Repost your comment as an answer, the OP might find this preferable to my suggestions.